# Convert Serial Port bytes (RS232) to text C#

Tags: c#, arrays, serial-port, byte

I am building a windows service for receiving weight from weight machine(`sartorius`). Weight machine is connected via `rs232`

Using below code.

```
                var sp = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
                sp.DtrEnable = true;
                sp.RtsEnable = false;
                sp.DataReceived += port_OnReceiveDatazz;
                if (!sp.IsOpen)
                {
                    sp.Open();
                }
```

and here is my `DataReceived` event.

```
        private void port_OnReceiveDatazz(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                SerialPort spL = (SerialPort)sender;
                byte[] buf = new byte[spL.BytesToRead];
                spL.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                string data = "";
                //buf=[32,32,50,174,56,56,182,176,32,227,244,32,13,138]
                //actual wt is 2.887
                //buf=[32,32,56,174,55,49,55,176,32,227,244,32,13,138]
                // actual wt is 8.7170
                foreach (Byte b in buf)
                {
                    data += Convert.ToString(b) + ",";
                }
                SendData(new WeightModel() { DateTime = DateTime.Now, Weight = data });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                WriteLog(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ex));
            }
        }
```

I am received following byte arrays from port.

`[32,32,50,174,56,56,182,176,32,227,244,32,13,138]`

`[32,32,56,174,55,49,55,176,32,227,244,32,13,138]`

Its output should be `2.887` and `8.7170` respectively.

I have tried below methods but not returning valid output.

1. `var str = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes);`
   it is returning this `"  2?88?? ?? \r?"`
2. `var str = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);`
   it is returning this `"  2�88�� �� \r�"`
3. `var str = BitConverter.ToString(bytes);`
   it is returning this `"20-20-32-AE-38-38-B6-B0-20-E3-F4-20-0D-8A"`

Returned outputs are for first array.

I also tried to get data like below

```
var data = spL.ReadExisting();
```

But this is returning data like   `8?712 ??`

Can you please help me to get original output from these byte arrays.

Comment: `SerialPort.ReadLine`? `SerialPort.ReadChar`? SerialPort has a bunch of stuff for dealing with strings already

Comment: I tried `SerialPort.ReadExisting()` but it is retruning data like `   8?712 ?? `

Comment: you get those weird results because the underlying encoding that is used here is ASCII which has its limit at `0x7F` or `127` in decimal. but your byte array shows clearly that this limit is exceeded. So it cannot interpret the charcters

Comment: @MongZhu `System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes)` is returning `"†긲㠸낶\u20f4訍"`

Comment: @MongZhu yes i have cross checked bound rate and other settings all are correct.

Comment: What Font,encoding, language is scale set to?  The diamonds with question marks is due to the viewer you are using to read results.  The viewer encoding is not matching the scale settings.  You do not need to change your code.  Just correct the viewer settings.

Comment: do me a favor and try to set the DataBits to 7. It is merely an educated guess.... actually try this setting: `new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.Odd, 7, StopBits.One);`

Comment: @MongZhu DataBIts is set to 8

Comment: and why do you set `sp.DtrEnable = true;` and `sp.RtsEnable = false;` does your documentation say so?

Comment: @MongZhu DataReceived event was not calling then I googled and found this

Comment: @MongZhu Yes I will try by setting DataBits to 7

Comment: It seems to be this company, but what model is it? [Weighing Balances, Moisture Analyzers, & More | Sartorius](https://www.sartorius.com/en/products/weighing) Also, please present any specifications or programming manuals that can be accessed from the web. If the material does not have web access, please add that part to the question. Without such specific and detailed information, it will take time wastefully.

Comment: If you mask off the top bit for all values (buf[x] &= 0x7F;) - then convert to ASCII you get " 2.8860 ct" & " 8.7170 ct"

Comment: @PaulF wouldn't that be the equivalent of setting DataBits to 7 ?

Comment: @MongZhu: You are right - my comment should have explained that would be what you get if you set 7 bit data. All I am doing is masking off the parity bit. I just showed the result of what you would get.

Comment: @PaulF cool thank you for the effort. I wonder who in future could ever profit from this post if we solve this issue.

Comment: @MongZhu: I think it may be useful if you add your comment as an answer, there are multiple ways of wrongly configuring the SerialPort which will get bad or partly bad data, so it highlights the need to check how the device at the far end is talking.

Comment: @PaulF  thanks man. I have checked with your suggestion (buf[x] &= 0x7F;). It worked. But I was not able to verify DataBIts because i am doing this remotely and I tested it with another guy. You can answer it and I will accept.

Comment: @Manoj: I prefer not to put my suggestion as an answer - as all I have down is get around the problem - the real answer is to set the correct DataBits & Parity, then the data you get back from the serial port will not need further processing. The reason you have values > 127 in your array is that they have the Parity bit set.

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be incorrect configuration of the Serial Port.

What appears to be required is 7bit data with Odd Parity and 1 stop bit. You have set up the Port to have 8 bit data, No parity & 1 stop bit. The configuration ends up with the correct number of bits per byte being sent, so no framing errors occur.

What is happening with that 8bit data you are getting is that the lower 7bits are the actual ASCII data you require, the top bit is actually the parity bit being sent.

What you need to do is correctly configure the serial port (7bit, odd parity & 1 stop bit) & the data you get from the Read methods will be 7bit only (the parity bit will be stripped at the device level).

If that is not a possibility, then you can mask off the parity bit by ANDing each character received with 0x7F - note that I believe this to be a bit of a hack to get around the real problem.